# Printing bit values on the position in the number

Tags: c#

I encountered a few problems when answering this question:
We are given number n and position p. Write a sequence of operations that prints the value of the bit on the position p in the number (0 or 1). Example: n=35, p=5 -> 1. Another example: n=35, p=6 -> 0.

What is the meaning of printing the value of the bit on the position p in the number??

bit of 35 (100011). If bits position are read from right to left, then why is the bit value for p=5 -> 1?

Comment: You need to ask that to the one who gave you this task, not us. People can't read minds. My best *guess* is that the bets are zero-based (which is the common way to count them). Bet then again, what do I know what the guy meant who gave you that task?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply! Its a question i found in an assessment book! I dont get what they meant by the 'value of the bit on the position p in the number'.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose here is to check the bit value in position x inside a given number.

It can be used to store security options. 
Example - bit 0 is read only, bit 1 is write, bit 2 is create new item etc.

You should read about Boolean math and understand how to represent a number in binary method. Then read about "AND" operations (then NOT, OR, XOR, XON).

[Here is a good link](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~dfg/hardware/HardwareLecture01.pdf)

I have some simple code for you to play with. I made the "checking" procedure long so you would understand. I could do it with a single line if wanted.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     int n ;

     int i ;

     string s;

     string b;

     n = 13;//1101 in binary representation

     i = 0;

     s = checkBitX(n,i);

     b =  Convert.ToString(n, 2);

     MessageBox.Show("Bit " + i.ToString() + " , in decimal number " + n.ToString() + ", binary = " + b +  " ,the bit is : " + s);


     i = 1;

     s = checkBitX(n, i);

     MessageBox.Show("Bit " + i.ToString() + " , in decimal number " + n.ToString() + ", binary = " + b + " ,the bit is : " + s);


  }
  private string checkBitX(int n, int i)
  {

     string s = "";

     int temp = (int)Math.Pow(2, i);

     int test = n & temp;

     if (test != 0)
     {
        s = "set";
     }
     else
     {
        s = "cleared";
     }

     return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> bit of 35 (100011). If bits position are read from right to left, then why is the bit value for p=5 -> 1?

Presumably they're talking about zero-based, so the rightmost bit would be `p=0`, and `p=5` is talking about the *sixth* bit.

In terms of math:

```
bool bitSet = ((n >> p) & 1) != 0;
```

is probably the easiest way to test it; so if `p` is 5, this right-shifts by 5 (dropping the right-most 5 bits) then tests whether the *now* right-most bit is a 1 or a 0.